# Angular ternary with html

Tags: angularjs

How can I include html in a ternary operator?

```
{{ (q.result === 1) ? "<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>" ? "<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>" }}
```

If not possible, I guess the obvious alternative is to do two wrapping element blocks with `<div ng-if="result">HTML</div>` and `<div ng-if="!result">OTHER HTML</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can acccomplish what you want with ng-class.  It actually supports the ternary operator

```
<i class="fa" aria-hidden="true" ng-class"(q.result === 1) ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change the class, use a conditional ng-class.

```
<i ng-class="q.result===1 ? 'fa fa-check' : 'fa fa-times' " aria-hidden="true">
```